# How to create script using Liquibase without providing the db details like url, user-name, password and driver?

Tags: liquibase

I created the `ddl` scripts using `liquibase` by providing the input `data base change log`.

The code looks like this

```
    private void toSQL(DatabaseChangeLog d)
        throws DatabaseException, LiquibaseException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    FileSystemResourceAccessor fsOpener = new FileSystemResourceAccessor();
    CommandLineResourceAccessor clOpener = new CommandLineResourceAccessor(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    CompositeResourceAccessor fileOpener = new CompositeResourceAccessor(new ResourceAccessor[] { fsOpener, clOpener });

    Database database = CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(fileOpener, this.url, this.username, this.password, this.driver, 
            this.defaultCatalogName, this.defaultSchemaName, Boolean.parseBoolean(this.outputDefaultCatalog),
            Boolean.parseBoolean(this.outputDefaultSchema), this.databaseClass, 
            this.driverPropertiesFile, this.propertyProviderClass, this.liquibaseCatalogName, 
            this.liquibaseSchemaName, this.databaseChangeLogTableName, this.databaseChangeLogLockTableName);


    Liquibase liquibase=new Liquibase(d, null, database);

    liquibase.update(new Contexts(this.contexts), new LabelExpression(this.labels), getOutputWriter());
}
```

and my `liquibase.properties` goes like this

```
url=jdbc\:sqlserver\://server\:1433;databaseName\=test
username=test
password=test@123
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:br.com.company.vacation.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

As you can see, Liquibase is expecting a lot of `db` parameters such as `url`,`username`,`password`,`driver`, which I will not be able to provide.

How can I achieve this without providing any of the parameters. Is it possible?

Comment: is your problem that you don't want to have online db or any db at all?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. If you want liquibase to interact with a database, you have to tell it how to connect to that database.

Comment: I don't want to interact with db, I just want to generate the ddl create script for the given change set.

Comment: OK - in that case, rather than the custom code you ae using, you could just use the liquibase `updateSql` command. You do have to tell it what type of database you are creating the SQL for, but you can use an offline database URL to do that. See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html

Answer (score 0):

I investigated a little about the `liquibase` operation in `offline mode`.  It goes like this.

Running in offline mode only supports `updateSql`, `rollbackSQL`, `tag`, and `tagExists`. It does not support direct `update, diff, or preconditions` as there is nothing to actually update or state to check.

An offline database is “connected” to using a url syntax of `offline:DATABASE_TYPE?param1=value1&aparam2=value2`.

The following code will suffice

```
this.url=offline:postgres?param1=value1&aparam2=value2;
this.driver=null;
this.username=null;
this.password=null;
```

Hence not providing the db details. Offline url can be made up from the store type.